# Socket server + Event source magic disconnect

Tags: php, sockets, server-sent-events

I've successfully implemented next scheme: a php socket server script that broadcasts message to all connected client scripts, and those client scripts are listened by event-source on the front-end script. So, basically, scheme is: `server.php` -> `client.php` -> `front.php`.

But I've been struggling with this part from `client.php`:

```
while(TRUE)
{
    $read   = array();
    $read[] = $client_socket;

    if( socket_select($read, $write, $except, 10) === FALSE ){
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
        file_put_contents("select_result.log", "Could not listen on socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg".PHP_EOL);
    }

    if( !($client_message = @socket_read($client_socket, 1024)) ){
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
        file_put_contents("read_result.log", "Couldn't read socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg".PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    }

    if($client_message == FALSE) {
        $client_message  = "event: keep_alive" . PHP_EOL
                         . "data: keep_alive" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo $client_message;

    if( ob_get_level() > 0 ) ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

When a open `front.php` script (which uses **event-source**) in browser, it works fine, **BUT** it also somehow detects disconnect, when I close or reload `front.php` in browser window. Here is part from `server.php` that detects disconnect:

```
if( !($client_input = @socket_read($client, 1024))) {
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    echo "$errorcode".PHP_EOL;
}

if ( $client_input === FALSE ) {
    $socket_key = array_search($client, $client_sockets);
    socket_getpeername($client, $client_address, $client_port);
    socket_close($client);//?!!!
    unset($client_sockets[$socket_key]);
    echo "[$client_address : $client_port disconnected]".PHP_EOL;
}
```

As you see, this happens when data cannot be read from client. Theoretically, when I close `front.php`, `client.php` should still be working in an endless cycle on background, as I haven't got any loop breaks, but - surprise! - it stops. Experimentally, I've found that this is happening due to `ob_flush()` function. When it's commented, `server.php` does not detect disconnect (browser window close/reload). How could it be? `ob_flush()` does not return any value, according to manual. No errors detected as well... I don't know what to think, and I can't find why this happening. Please, help.

Comment: Is "front.php" the HTML page, containing JavaScript, etc. I.e. it could really be called "front.html" for purposes of this question? (Or, is front.php what your HTML clients connect to using EventSource?). In other words, in your browser-run JavaScript, do you do `new EventSource("client.php")` or do `new EventSource("front.php")` ?

Comment: You are correct, yes, it could be easily called `front.html`, and I do `new EventSource("client.php")`; `client.php` then opens socket connection to `server.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Apache or something in front of client.php. What happens when your front.php runs `var es = new EventSource('client.php')` is that a dedicated TCP/IP socket is created between the browser and Apache. Apache runs PHP, telling it to load and run client.php.  (And client.php then creates a socket to listen to messages from server.php.)

When the browser is shut (or you call `es.close()`, or for some reason the socket connection between browser and Apache gets lost), then Apache will immediately(*) close down the PHP process (the one running client.php). And when that PHP process disappears, the socket between client.php and server.php will get closed (either immediately, or the next time server.php tries to read/write to it).

*: usually "immediately". Sometimes if a socket is not closed cleanly it can hang around for a little while (a matter of seconds, never more than a minute).

I think your `ob_flush()` observation is a bit of red herring; my guess would be that by not calling `ob_flush()` there is something stuck in a buffer, which means Apache keeps the PHP process alive until some time-out expires. Incidentally, I use the `@ob_flush();@flush()` idiom; the `@` before `ob_flush()` is basically doing what your `ob_get_level()` check is doing (but I vaguely remember hearing there is a situation where that check is not always reliable).

Comment: Wow, from your answer I've exactly understood what is happening... Yet again you really helped me out with my project. Cheers : )

Answer (score 0):

Flushing the output buffer to the browser does not work (anymore) as expected with recent version of Chrome/Firefox.

You would need some kind of `register_shutdown_func()` which does not work stable aswell for the purpose you want it.

It's generally very unstable to put client/server in a PHP script loaded through the browser due to the design of the HTTP protocol. It is not designed to keep connections alive and send messages the way IRC for example works. HTTP connections can close due to many reasons mostly after 30-60 seconds.

I suggest you to use the PHP command line version for the server and JavaScript for the client purpose.

Also the way you load PHP (mod_php in apache?) affects the whole thing. How many threads/forks of PHP/Apache do you open, how many connections does every process hold,..

Some webservers kill any scripts when the page finished loading after some seconds, its hard to debug and hard to get stable.

Try WebRTC / WebSockets in JavaScript, it's way better for this and integrates better into any HTML5 site.

Comment: Thank you for response; however, I've tested this scheme over various browsers (old/new versions, including IE 8+) and two different servers (not mentioning localhost). You misunderstood a bit, because I am running `server.php` via command line, with JavaScript event-source `front.php` for client that starts and listens `client.php` output. Connection are kept alive by sending some `data:` every 10 seconds (could be more). All you said is reasonable, but time is short - I can't re-write everything with, say, WebSockets. It's only minor `ob_flush` issue that really bothers me.